# Map KinectV2 depth to rgb DSLR

Tags: opencv, processing, kinect, edsdk

I am trying to map the depth from the Kinectv2 to RGB space from a DSLR camera and I am stuck with weird pixel mapping.

I am working on Processing, using OpenCV and Nicolas Burrus' method where :

```
P3D.x = (x_d - cx_d) * depth(x_d,y_d) / fx_d
P3D.y = (y_d - cy_d) * depth(x_d,y_d) / fy_d
P3D.z = depth(x_d,y_d)

P3D' = R.P3D + T
P2D_rgb.x = (P3D'.x * fx_rgb / P3D'.z) + cx_rgb
P2D_rgb.y = (P3D'.y * fy_rgb / P3D'.z) + cy_rgb
```

Unfortunatly i have a problem when I reproject 3D point to RGB World Space. In order to check if the problem came from my OpenCV calibration I used MRPT Kinect & Setero Calibration in order to get the intrinsics and distorsion coefficients of the cameras and the rototranslation relative transformation between the two cameras.

[eDatas from stereo calibration MRPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPuaT.png)

Here my datas :

```
depth c_x = 262.573912;
depth c_y = 216.804166;
depth f_y = 462.676558;
depth f_x = 384.377033;
depthDistCoeff = {
    1.975280e-001, -6.939150e-002, 0.000000e+000, -5.830770e-002, 0.000000e+000
  };


DSLR c_x_R = 538.134412;
DSLR c_y_R = 359.760525;
DSLR f_y_R = 968.431461;
DSLR f_x_R = 648.480385;
rgbDistCoeff = {
    2.785566e-001, -1.540991e+000, 0.000000e+000, -9.482198e-002, 0.000000e+000
  };

R = {
    8.4263457190597e-001, -8.9789363922252e-002, 5.3094712387890e-001,
    4.4166517232817e-002, 9.9420220953803e-001, 9.8037162878270e-002,
    -5.3667149820385e-001, -5.9159417476295e-002, 8.4171483671105e-001 
  };

T = {-4.740111e-001, 3.618596e-002, -4.443195e-002};
```

Then I use the data in processing in order to compute the mapping using :

```
PVector pixelDepthCoord = new PVector(i * offset_, j * offset_);
        int index = (int) pixelDepthCoord .x + (int) pixelDepthCoord .y * depthWidth;
        int depth = 0;

        if (rawData[index] != 255)
        {
          //2D Depth Coord
          depth = rawDataDepth[index];
        } else
        {
        }

        //3D Depth Coord - Back projecting pixel depth coord to 3D depth coord
        float bppx = (pixelDepthCoord.x - c_x) * depth / f_x;
        float bppy = (pixelDepthCoord.y - c_y) * depth /  f_y;
        float bppz = -depth;

        //transpose 3D depth coord to 3D color coord
        float x_ =(bppx * R[0] + bppy * R[1] + bppz * R[2]) + T[0];
        float y_ = (bppx * R[3] + bppy * R[4] + bppz * R[5]) + T[1];
        float z_ = (bppx * R[6] + bppy * R[7] + bppz * R[8]) + T[2];

        //Project 3D color coord to 2D color Cood
        float pcx = (x_ * f_x_R / z_) + c_x_R;
        float pcy = (y_ * f_y_R / z_) + c_y_R;
```

Then i get the following transformations :

[Weird mapping behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQD2v.png)

I think i have a probleme in my method but i don't get it. Does anyone has any ideas or a clues. I am racking my brain since many days on this problem ;)

Thanks